# VisJS Network Graph not stabilizing and moving in circle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, react-vis

I am trying to create a network graph using `visjs` but the problem is it works for one set of nodes and edges but doesn't work for the other.

**The data (nodes and edges) can vary so is there a way I can provide a generic settings?**

As in the given example the graph keeps on moving in a circle and takes forever to stabilize. Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/aqarain92/eL1qt58r/16/

I am using the following `options`

```
const options = {
      nodes: {
        shape: "dot",
        scaling: {
          min: 3,
          max: 70
        }
      },
      edges: {
        arrows: { to: { enabled: false } },
        width: 1,
        color: {
          color: 'gray',
          highlight: 'black'
        },
        smooth: { type: "continuous", roundness: 0 }
      },
      groups: {
        authentic: { color: 'blue' },
        inauthentic: { color: 'purple' },
        parent: { color: 'black' }
      },
      layout: { improvedLayout: false },
      physics: {
        forceAtlas2Based: {
          gravitationalConstant: -26,
          centralGravity: 0.005,
          springLength: 100,
          springConstant: 0.04
        },
        maxVelocity: 146,
        solver: "forceAtlas2Based",
        timestep: 0.35,
        stabilization: { iterations: 200 }
      },
      interaction: {
        tooltipDelay: 200,
        hideEdgesOnDrag: true,
        hideEdgesOnZoom: true
      }
    };
```

The same options work for different set of nodes and edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too late, here is the stabilized version of your network:

https://jsfiddle.net/8nowe7c4/

I changed your options a little bit:

```
const options = {
  nodes: {
    shape: "dot",
    scaling: {
      min: 3,
      max: 70
    }
  },
  edges: {
    arrows: { to: { enabled: false } },
    width: 1,
    color: {
      color: 'gray',
      highlight: 'black'
    },
    smooth: { type: "continuous", roundness: 0 }
  },
  groups: {
    authentic: { color: 'blue' },
    inauthentic: { color: 'purple' },
    parent: { color: 'black' }
  },
  layout: { improvedLayout: false },
  physics: {
    forceAtlas2Based: {
      gravitationalConstant: -126,
      springLength: 200,
      springConstant: 0.01
    },
    maxVelocity: 50,
    solver: "forceAtlas2Based",
    timestep: 0.35,
    stabilization: true
  },
  interaction: {
    tooltipDelay: 200,
    hideEdgesOnDrag: true,
    hideEdgesOnZoom: true
  }
};
```

You may tune the parameters for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much but can you please explain a little that what you did and how it fixed the issue?

Comment: Your spring lengths were too short and they were too sturdy, which I think caused that stabilization problem in the first place. I made them a little bit relaxed. Then, decreased the gravitational constant by -100 to make your nodes to be pushed away from the center. Lastly, doubled the central gravity to pull them together.

Comment: Is it possible that we create a network graph with 10 nodes and then on clicking a button add 10 extra nodes to the relevant parent nodes?

Comment: Yes, just add new nodes and edges and call update method of DataSet instances for both nodes and edges.

Comment: I am sorry can you please elaborate it a little.

Comment: I preferred to update your fiddle to show you how to do that. There are comments in JS part and you can follow them to understand the details. Have fun! https://jsfiddle.net/3vhg69ac/

Comment: I am sorry for being late but I can't thank you enough sir for your help and time. Thank you so much. If you don't mind, can I please add you on LinkedIn?

Comment: You're welcome, and of course: https://www.linkedin.com/in/caner-elci-60a5284  (I hope it's allowed to share such information as a comment here)